# Unable to start sphinx in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, thinking-sphinx

I have installed Sphinx from source with pgsql and then installed thinking-sphinx gem(3.0.1)  on my application (Rails 4.0.3). And I configured & generated the sphinx configurations. Then I added the indices on app/indices and later ran the index & start the sphinx via rake ts:index && ts:start, but I got the below error, let me know the way to resolve this.

> rake ts:index

Generating configuration to `/home/stc/presto/config/development.sphinx.conf`

> > Sphinx 2.1.7-release (rel21-r4638)
> >
> > Copyright (c) 2001-2014, Andrew Aksyonoff
> >
> > Copyright (c) 2008-2014, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
> >
> > using config file '/home/stc/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
> >
> > FATAL: no indexes found in config file '/home/stc/config/development.sphinx.conf'
>
> rake ts:start

*In the log file I can see the below errors*

```
[Wed Apr  2 10:40:49.834 2014] [14338] Child process 14339 has been forked
[Wed Apr  2 10:40:49.835 2014] [14339] listening on 127.0.0.1:9306
[Wed Apr  2 10:40:49.835 2014] [14339] WARNING: ERROR: index 'collection_core': RT indexes support prefixes and infixes with only dict=keywords - NOT SERVING
[Wed Apr  2 10:40:49.836 2014] [14339] WARNING: ERROR: index 'resource_core': RT indexes support prefixes and infixes with only dict=keywords - NOT SERVING
[Wed Apr  2 10:40:49.836 2014] [14339] WARNING: index 'collection': no such local index 'collection_core' - SKIPPING LOCAL INDEX
[Wed Apr  2 10:40:49.836 2014] [14339] WARNING: index 'collection': no valid local/remote indexes in distributed index - NOT SERVING
[Wed Apr  2 10:40:49.836 2014] [14339] WARNING: index 'resource': no such local index 'resource_core' - SKIPPING LOCAL INDEX
[Wed Apr  2 10:40:49.836 2014] [14339] WARNING: index 'resource': no valid local/remote indexes in distributed index - NOT SERVING
[Wed Apr  2 10:40:49.836 2014] [14339] FATAL: no valid indexes to serve
[Wed Apr  2 10:40:49.836 2014] [14338] Child process 14339 has been finished, exit code 1. Watchdog finishes also. Good bye!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressed this on the Thinking Sphinx Google group as well:

You seem to be using real-time indices - which is great - but that means you don’t need to use the ts:index task. The two main tasks that are useful are:

- ts:generate - which adds/updates all documents in each real-time index.
- ts:regenerate - which stops Sphinx, clears out existing index files, generates the configuration, starts Sphinx and runs ts:generate.

However, you’re also using either min_infix_len or min_prefix_len - and with Sphinx 2.1, the default dict setting doesn’t match with what is needed (as the logs detail). So, if you add dict: keywords to the appropriate environments in config/thinking_sphinx.yml and then run ts:regenerate, you should hopefully have a working Sphinx setup.